# Can I get the opener window from a ModalDialog window?

Tags: javascript

Normally when a window is opened using window.open I can access the caller window by using window.opener(), is it possible do the similar within modal dialogs(window.showModalDialog)?

Comment: Related: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759.aspx

Comment: The answer is in the link. I can't work out a full answer right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can read in a [comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759.aspx#16) on the MSDN page about [`showModalDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759.aspx) (thanks to Pekka),

> [t]he `window.opener` method returns
>   `null`, rather than a reference to the
>   opening window. So you cannot refresh
>   the opening window with
>   `window.opener.location.refresh()`
>   (if, for instance, you use
>   `showModalDialog` to open an editing
>   dialog). If all you want to do is
>   refresh the opening window every time
>   the `ModalDialog` closes, that is easy
>   (include `window.location.refresh()`
>   right after the call to
>   `showModalDialog`).  But if you only
>   want to refresh the opening window in
>   certain cases (e.g., the opening
>   window takes a while to refresh), you
>   can do that by passing a
>   `dialogArgument`.
>
> A more clever (I think) way is to
>   **pass the window reference itself as the `dialogArgument`**.  In the
>   calling window, use
>   `window.showModalDialog('newurl.asp',
>   window)`.  In the called dialog
>   retrieve the reference with `var
>   window_opener =
>   window.dialogArguments`.  You can use
>   the window reference stored in
>   variable `window_opener` in place of
>   `window.opener`, to refresh the
>   calling window from the called dialog.
>
> Do note that Firefox and Chrome (for
>   instance) do not appear to have these
>   limitations, and appear to treat
>   `ModalDialogs` more like regular
>   windows.  Keep that in mind if you do
>   testing using one of these browsers,
>   but intend your application to work in
>   all browsers.