# Refresh parent form from modal dialog in CRM 4 - doesnt always work

Tags: javascript, refresh, modal-dialog, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a modal dialog and I want to refresh the parent form when I close the dialog.

I have used this javascript code:

```
self.close();
window.dialogArguments.location.reload(true);
```

The problem is that it doesnt always refreshes the parent form. Sometimes it refreshes and sometimes it doesnt and I can't figure out why it doesn't refreshes always?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it's intermittent because sometimes your `self.close();` completes before reaching the next line.

Basically, swap those two statements over and I expect you will see consistent performance.

Comment: Actually when I look at your code, I don't think I understand what the second line is doing... Are you looking to refresh, from the dialog, the page that spawned the dialog?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109532/can-i-get-the-opener-window-from-a-modaldialog-window